# ubuntu cobbler server - importing distros

Tags: 12.04, server, pxe

I setup and fully configured ubuntu-12.04-server machine with cobbler/dhcp running in about 10 minutes (compared to taking over an hour on centos 5.8). I discovered the cobbler import which appears to be useful. Does this remove the need to use a cobbler distro add? whenever I run a cobbler report after a successful import of ubuntu desktop iso:

```
sudo cobbler import --name=Ubuntu --path=/mnt --breed=debian
task started: 2012-12-13_163245_import
task started (id=Media import, time=Thu Dec 13 16:32:45 2012)
Found a debian/ubuntu compatible signature: pool
adding distros
avoiding symlink loop
avoiding symlink loop
avoiding symlink loop
associating repos
associating kickstarts
*** TASK COMPLETE ***
```

I just get the following (nothing):

```
distros:
==========

profiles:
==========

systems:
==========

repos:
==========

images:
==========

mgmtclasses:
==========

packages:
==========

files:
==========
```

I was rather hoping that I wouldn't have to do the traditional copying of all files in /mnt to a new /distro directory and then perform a cobbler distro add --initrd=/path/to/inird --kernel=/path/to/kernel

Maybe I am mistaken about what the import actually does for me. If someone could elaborate on what the import is actually for please do.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late in the day but I think you got the breed wrong.

```
sudo cobbler import --name=precise --path=/mnt --breed=ubuntu
```

works for me

```
distros:
==========
Name                           : Precise-x86_64
Architecture                   : x86_64
TFTP Boot Files                : {}
Breed                          : ubuntu
Comment                        : ubuntu precise (12.04.0) None
Fetchable Files                : {}
Initrd                         :   /var/www/cobbler/ks_mirror/Precise/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
Kernel                         : /var/www/cobbler/ks_mirror/Precise/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
Kernel Options                 : {}
Kernel Options (Post Install)  : {}
Kickstart Metadata             : {'tree': 'http://@@http_server@@/cblr/ks_mirror/Precise'}
Management Classes             : []
OS Version                     : precise
Owners                         : ['admin']
Red Hat Management Key         : <<inherit>>
Red Hat Management Server      : <<inherit>>
Template Files                 : {}
```

Also, use the server or alternate iso's, not desktop.

Also note the existence of

```
 cobbler-ubuntu-import
```

Which does the same without the need to download a iso.